# App Crash on Table Row load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, watchkit

I'm pulling data in from CloudKit, and there is only one item in the data.

Once the `matchup` **loads**, and **before** the background color is seen in the UI, the **app crashes**.  I can't figure out why, any ideas?

`InterfaceController` on Watch:

```
func loadTable() {
    self.rowTable.setNumberOfRows(self.matchupArray.count, withRowType: "rows")
    let rowCount = self.rowTable.numberOfRows

    for i in 0...rowCount  {
        let row = self.rowTable.rowController(at: i) as! Rows!
        row?.matchup.setText(self.matchupArray[i])
        let colorBackground = UIColor.init(hex: self.teamColorArray[i])
        row?.groupColor.setBackgroundColor(colorBackground)
    }

}

func getData() {
    cloud.getCloudKit { (game: [GameWatch]) in
        var teamColorArray = [String]()
        var matchupArray = [String]()

        for item in game {
            teamColorArray.append(item.teamColor)
            matchupArray.append(item.matchup)
        }

        self.teamColorArray = teamColorArray
        self.matchupArray = matchupArray

        self.loadTable()
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**:

**Got a crash, with the error "fatal error: Index out of range".**

I'm not sure why this is, because the `matchupArray.count` is 1, the `rowCount` is 1. It started iterating through the `for-loop` with `i` as 0, and finished the first iteration where it should have stopped since there was only 1 item.  But I got the crash because it started to iterate through the loop again, with `i` as 1, and then obviously found nothing so it crashed.

**The crash comes after `row?.matchup.setText(self.matchupArray[i])` is run.**

Comment: if you are doing this row?.groupColor.setBackgroundColor(colorBackground) on background thread app might crash

Comment: @KuntalGajjar thanks for the response! Hmm, that might be it, does it look like I'm on a background thread? Just wondering because it doesn't look like I'm hopping on a background thread for `getCloudKit` but I might totally be missing something that someone like yourself might see quicker than me.

Comment: can you try doing this self.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(CLASSNAME. loadTable), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)

Comment: @KuntalGajjar do that where?

Comment: instead of doing self.loadTable() inside your getData() write the code that I sent you

Comment: does that works for you?

Comment: @KuntalGajjar let me give it a try real quick for sure, and then I'll report back

Comment: There is no need to guess. There will be a crash log that gives the exact reason that the app has crashed and execution will stop at the exact line that caused the problem. Add this information as text to your question.

Comment: @RoboticCat its been a tough go because the Watch Simulator and CloudKit don't play together well (CloudKit usage is blocked on watchOS Simulators), so I feel like I'm in the dark a bit.  Have you found any workarounds for that?  If so definitely let me know, maybe I missed it!

Comment: @SRMR: I'm not familiar with the Watch Simulator but there's always a crash log and execution in the simulator will stop at the line of your code with the exception. In the crash log there is an error message that will tell you why you crashed. Also, what happens with the debugger when you step through your code?

Comment: @RoboticCat let me know if I'm talking about something different than you, but I can't get CloudKit data on the Watch Simulator, so I can't even get to the part where I'd want to step thru, because all my data is empty.  So for example, when I get to `loadTable()` there is no data to iterate thru, and the crash would definitely be happening some where in there. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SRMR: If there's no data in your app then there will be no data in your `matchupArray` and you will crash when you try to access index `0`. The error message in your crash log will be similar to `index out of bounds`. Check the crash log on the console for the exact error message.

Comment: @RoboticCat right, but CloudKit does work on a device if I use TestFlight, etc.  So there is data, and the crash I'm getting can only be replicated on a Watch Device, because there's no data if I try to do it in the Watch Simulator.  So the crashes in the Simulator don't help me you know?

Comment: @RoboticCat I finally got my watch paired with the simulator so I could run it on device but also have the log.  I got error "fatal error: Index out of range".  Which was weird because I only have 1 item in the array, and it iterated through that, then went back to iterate through again (and I'm not sure why since there's only 1 item in the array) and then crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: @KuntalGajjar I got a crash and posted the code for the error above.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like the error is the line `for i in 0...rowCount` when it should be `for i in 0..<rowCount`.

Comment: @RoboticCat yup thats exactly it.  If you want to put it as an answer I can accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the line:

```
for i in 0...rowCount
```

This `...` operator creates a range of indexes that includes both values when, because Swift uses 0-based arrays, you need the `..<` operator to create a range that excludes the upper value.

This line should therefore be:

```
for i in 0..<rowCount
```